# Big Oh induction proof

Tags: induction, asymptotics

I am trying to prove the following through Big Oh induction:

$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2\quad when\quad n\geq2\quad prove\quad T(n)\in O(n^2)\quad$ with a base case of $\quad T(1) = 1$

I've taken the following steps:

Base Case: $n=2 \quad T(2) = 3T(\frac{2}{2}) + 2^2 = 3*1+4 = 7 \leq c*2^2 = c*4$

Where I can pick c to make this true $7 \leq c*4$

Inductive Step:

Assume $T(k) \leq c*k^2 \quad$ for all $\quad k \leq n$

$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2})+n^2 \leq 3(c*\frac{n^2}{2^2})+n^2 = c*n^2*\frac{3}{4}+n^2 $

Now I know I need to get this to be $\quad \leq c*n^2 \quad$ but I don't know how to negate the $\quad \frac{3}{4} + n^2 \quad$ that is left over. I don't think I can just say "when $\quad c \geq \frac{3}{4}+n^2$". What are your suggestions?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you just need to prove that $T(n)\le cn^2$ holds for some $c$. You can choose whatever $c$ you want. In order to get
$$
\frac34 c n^2+n^2\le cn^2,
$$
all you need is
$$
\frac34 c+ 1\le c,
$$
so choose any $c$ for which that is true.

Comment: ok I think i get it. So the work would look like $\frac{3}{4}cn^2+n^2 \leq cn^2 ---> \frac{3}{4}cn^2 \leq cn^2-n^2 --->\frac{3}{4}cn^2 \leq n^2(c-1) --->\frac{3}{4}c \leq c-1--- > \frac{3}{4}c+1 \leq $